# python 3 for loop "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

I want to change color specific coordinates. I can take all x, y coordinates and change to color in for loop. My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import math
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

im = Image.open('harita2.png').convert("RGB")
npimage = np.array(im)
g1= np.array([93,95,95],dtype=np.uint8)
g2= np.array([54,55,55],dtype=np.uint8)
g3= np.array([84,86,86],dtype=np.uint8)
s= np.array([0,0,0],dtype=np.uint8)
#print(g1)
x1,y1=np.where(np.all((npimage==g1),axis=-1))
print(x1)
tt = x1.size
tt = int(tt)
print(tt)
print(x1[15])
print(y1[15])   

for vvv in tt:
    idraw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    idraw.point((x1[vvv],y1[vvv]),s)

im.save('boyatest.png')
```

This is my output:

```
[   0    0    0 ... 2585 2585 2585]
59306
0
2595
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t11.py", line 22, in <module>
    for vvv in tt:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

What’s going wrong?

Comment: `tt` seems an integer and is not iterable.

Comment: yes but i must be need for loop x1.size time again

Comment: You actively wrote `int(tt)`. `int` objects are not iterable. Maybe you want `range(tt)` to iterate over every `int` from `0` to `tt-1`

Comment: @user8408080 Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 12
for i in count:
    print(i)
```

> Output: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer is to use python function [range](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/int-object-is-not-iterable-python-error-solved)

```
count = 12 
for i in range(count):
    print(i)
```

> Output: 0
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> 6
> 7
> 8
> 9
> 10
> 11

Source: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/int-object-is-not-iterable-python-error-solved